# JavaScript: getElementByID and mailTo issue

Tags: javascript, innerhtml, getelementbyid, mailto

So I'm trying to add a mailto with javascript but i cannot do this

```
document.getElementById("email").innerHTML = <a href="mailto:arr1[0].analy1.email?">;
```

because this produces a couple of errors. In my javascript code arr1[0].analy1.email actually holds an email address and I can get the email address to show up on my page with

```
document.getElementById("email").innerHTML = arr1[0].analy1.email;
```

but I need to know how to make this innerHTML email an actual mailto: link...

Answer (score 2):

String concatenation:

```
document.getElementById("email").innerHTML = '<a href="mailto:' + arr1[0].analy1.email + '">';
```

Or with the new ECMAScript 6 template strings:

```
document.getElementById('email').innerHTML = `<a href="mailto:${arr1[0].analy1.email}">`
```

Comment: should be `'<a href="mailto:' + arr1[0].analy1.email + '">';`

Comment: @Orland -- Ahh - yep - fixed.

Comment: Not really, it wasn't. Also, innerHTML is bad practice and leads to XSS.

Answer (score 2):

Other than string concatenation as @tymeJV's answer you can alternatively use DOM API to create and insert DOM elements

```
var email = document.getElementById("email"),
    a = document.createElement('a');
if (email.hasChildNodes()) {
    email.removechild(email.firstChild);
}
a.href = 'mailto:' + arr1[0].analy1.email;
a.textContent = arr1[0].analy1.email; // This will add the actual text to the link

email.appendChild(a);
```

Comment: This works, but when I run my function again the email value for arr1[0].analy1.email  still seems to be in memory , so when I run this again it will appendChild(a) to the previous value thus I get 2 email address links in a row and then 3 if I run it again. Is there a way I can reset this so that only the new value of arr1[0].analy1.email gets set and the old one does not display?  I guess I can make an if statement sayng if var a !== null then make it null or clear it when run this code.

Comment: you can `removechild()` from `email` before, I edited.